# Saving changes only between two hierarchical List

Tags: c#, algorithm, list, tree, treeview

This is a very conceptual question and I might get -ves for this. But bear with me please.

I have 2 `List<myType>` containing hierarchy of data in memory from two treeviews. One original and one updated. `myType` has self join property thus the tree structure. 

Currently, I am clearing the whole table and saving the updated list to my database.
Since that is not efficient how do I go about comparing them and **saving the changes only** to my database?

Following is a scenario:

```
List<Person> tree1 = new List<Person>();
tree1.Add
    (
        new Person() 
        { 
            Name = "Sr. John", 
            Age = 15, 
            People = new List<Person>() 
            {
                new Person() 
                { 
                    Name="John", 
                    Age=10, 
                    People=null 
                } 
            } 
        }
    );
```

```
List<Person> tree2 = new List<Person>();
tree2.Add
    (
        new Person() 
        { 
            Name = "Sr. John", 
            Age = 15, 
            People = new List<Person>() 
            { 
                new Person() 
                { 
                    Name = "John", 
                    Age = 10, 
                    People = new List<Person>()
                    {
                        new Person()
                        {
                            Name = "Jr. John",
                            Age = 5,
                            People = null
                        }
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        }
    );
```

Comment: How do you identify that 2 persons are the same person? What is the schema of your database?

Comment: I have a single table person with a `Reference` primary key field along with `Name` and `Age` and another field that EF generates for self joining classes that `Reference_Person`. I just want to lets say merge 2 lists mentioned above into one with changes only applied to it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have multiple references to the same person, you can use following algorithm.

It requires `Person` class to implement [IEquatable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131190.aspx) interface, and return `true` if 2 objects identify the same person: have the same `Reference` PK (if you have it filled in both trees) or `Name` and `Age`; but comparison should ignore children (should NOT compare `People` member).

```
private static List<Person> EmptyList = new List<Person>();
void SaveDifference(List<Person> treeold, List<Person> treenew)
{
    foreach(var pers in treenew)
    {
        int index = treeold.IndexOf(pers);
        if(index >= 0)
        {   // node exists in both lists, check chlid nodes:
            SaveDifference(treeold[index].People, pers.People);
            treeold.RemoveAt(index);
        }
        else
        {   // new added node
            // TODO: Store 'pers' to database (and update references in parent)
            SaveDifferences(EmptyList, pers.People)
        }
    }

    foreach(var pers in treeold)
    {   // node was deleted
        SaveDifferences(pers.People, EmptyList);
        // TODO: remove 'pers' from DB (and update references in parent)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I did not understand the use actually. When I implement `IEquatable` it gives me `Equals(Type other)` method. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: `SaveDifference` method above uses `IndexOf` method to find a person from the 'new' list in the 'old' list. The `IndexOf` method uses `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` (see MSDN), which in turn uses `IEquatable<Person>.Equals` to determine if 2 given objects from the lists represent the same person. F.i., in your example code you have created *2 different instances* of `Sr. John`, so default method will compare *references* and return false. Therefore you have to provide `Equals` method that will compare fields that uniquely identify a person (f.e. `Name` field).